# How to properly format the output in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, type-conversion, hex, octal

This is my code:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        print("{0: d} {0: o} {0: x} {0: b}".format(i)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

And the expected output and my output are in the image link given below.

[This is the image of my output and the expected output in hackerrank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1S5U.jpg)

[This is the code i have written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NBva.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include code, desired output, and current output as text in the question. See [here for more information](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(number):
    i = i+1
    
    pad = len("{0:b}".format(number))
    width = ''
    for j in range(pad):
        width = width + ' '
    # print ("{}".format(width) + "{0:o}".format(int(i)), end="")
    # print ("{}".format(width) + "{0:X}".format(int(i)), end="")
    # print ("{}".format(width) + "{0:b}".format(int(i)))
    print ("{}".format(i).rjust(pad, ' '), end="")
    print (("{0:o}".format(int(i))).rjust(pad+1, ' '), end="")
    print (("{0:X}".format(int(i))).rjust(pad+1, ' '), end="")
    print (("{0:b}".format(int(i))).rjust(pad+1, ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is HackerRank's "String Formatting" Python challenge, what your code is missing here is the "Each value should be space-padded to match the width of the binary value of n." part of the instructions. So you need to determine the length in digits of the binary version of your function's "number" input parameter, and then print each of the decimal, octal, hex, and binary versions of the numbers from 1 to "number" with leading spaces to, again, match that length. With the example test case of 2 from your screenshot, because 2 in binary -- 10 -- is two digits long, all the numbers you printed that were only one digit long need to be padded with a leading space, for example " 1" instead of "1".